# Firebase what is the new equivalent to .com/nextLevel

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2

in the new firebase with swift how do i do?

```
 var roomRef = Firebase(url: "https://appName.firebaseio.com/NextLevel")
```

the new syntax is

```
var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

I dont understand it
how do i get to Next Level?
if that makes any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var roomRef = rootRef.child('NextLevel');
```

This will get a reference to the same location as before.

Also see our [JavaScript upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_a_database_reference_numbered), although I'm not sure we cover it there yet.